# remove Spacing between lines

Tags: spacing, line

I am new at lyx. i have a document that i want to remove all the Spaces between lines. The goal is that the page will be compressed as much as possible. Attached part of the document. if you can halp me, I tried to look for solution but can't find a solution that works. 
[image]

Comment: `\baselineskip=0pt`

Comment: `\rule{1in}{1in}`: all pixels of the page compressed to a square. ;-)

Comment: `\offinterlineskip` that disables the normal line spacing with `\baselineskip` and also sets `\lineskip` to zero.

Comment: I try to catch it in the document - Settings - LATEX but it brings me error:
\ baselineskip, \ Lineskip: missing number, treaed as zero...

Answer (score 1):

A) <kbd>Document</kbd> > <kbd>Setings ...</kbd> > <kbd>Text layout</kbd> >

1. Set Vertical Space in **Paragraph separation** to <kbd>Custom</kbd> and `0` <kbd>pt</kbd>.
2. Set **Line spacing** to <kbd>Single</kbd> or even <kbd>Custom</kbd> with some value below 1.

B) Set spaces around the display mode:

```
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
```

But not in the preamble, so you will need a ERT TeX box (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) to insert this at some point before the first formula.

Alternatively, in the Math toolbar, change the display mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
by online mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) but if you maintain formulas at center do not use the normal center environment as this increase the vertical space. Use a ERT box with `\hfil` before each formula.

BTW, beside the horrible layout, it is not a good idea fix every length to `0pt` as this limit LaTeX options to fit things properly. Whenever possible left some glue, like `2pt plus 1 pt minus 1 pt`.